# Getting error in DynamoDB connectivity through node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Getting the following error while fetching dynamoDB table data With Node.js :

```
"message": "Requested resource not found",
"code": "ResourceNotFoundException",
"time": "2019-08-22T12:21:13.050Z",
      "requestId": "AGHIKJSM1CI8I4NNL1TRMT8HB7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
      "statusCode": 400,
      "retryable": false,
      "retryDelay": 6.227061109627718
```

The code I'm using:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

let awsConfig = {
    accessKeyId: "Some Key",
    secretAccessKey: "Some Key",

    region: "us-east-1"
};

AWS.config.update(awsConfig);
let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
let fetchOneByKey = function() {
  var params = {
    TableName: "Post",
    Key: {
      postId: "1566471620.204"
    }
  };

  docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(
        "AdminUser::fetchOneByKey::error - " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
      );
    } else {
      console.log(
        "AdminUser::fetchOneByKey::success - " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
  });
};
fetchOneByKey();
```

Comment: it could be you dont have a table?

Comment: check if the table exists in the correct region

Comment: I am getting this error a lot lately, and there doesn't seem to be any reason for it